# UTF-8 while compiling C++ for Geant 4

Tags: c++, utf-8

I am trying to run a program called Geant4, and I have this make file containing numerous .cc files involved in the program, but when I run it I get this error:

```
/Volumes/Silviu/Geant4/geant4.10.02.p02/examples/basic/B1/src/._B1PrimaryGeneratorAction.cc:1:4096: error: 
      source file is not valid UTF-8
```

I am not sure how to provide more details, but the point is that I have a file called B1PrimaryGeneratorAction.cc, but I am not sure what the error means, or what ._B1PrimaryGeneratorAction.cc actually represent. And what is a not valit UTF-8? Can anyone help please?

Comment: [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Need a baseline to work from. Do you know what UTF-8 is, or will answers have to start there?

Answer (score 0):

Inspect the "._B1PrimaryGeneratorAction.cc" file reported there. The name seems suspicious, maybe you extracted an archive incorrectly thus having a broken source file.

Also the position info ":1:4096" is kind of suspicious - it says that the invalid character is the 4096th character on the first line. Sounds like a corrupted file to me, just check that file contents (C++ source files usually do not have 4096 characters on a single line, although there can be exceptions indeed).

As far as I can tell, this might be the correct contents of the file:
http://geant4.web.cern.ch/geant4/UserDocumentation/Doxygen/examples_doc/html/B1PrimaryGeneratorAction_8cc_source.html
(and that file does not seem to contain any "strange" non-ASCII characters)